# can I use a variable for the integer expression in a left sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT top 2500 *
    FROM  table a
    LEFT JOIN table b
    ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
    WHERE left(a.employee_rc,6) IN 
           (
             SELECT employeeID, access 
             FROM   accesslist 
             WHERE  employeeID = '#client.id#' 
           )
```

The sub select in the `where` clause can return one or several access values, ex:

- js1234 BLKHSA
- js1234 HDF48R7
- js1234 BLN6

In the primary `where` clause I need to be able to change the integer expression from 6 to 5 or 4 or 7 depending on what the length of the values returned in the sub select. I am at a loss if this is the right way to go about it. I have tried using OR statements but it really slows down the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `exists` instead:

```
   SELECT top 2500 *
   FROM table a LEFT JOIN
        table b
        ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
   WHERE EXISTS (Select 1
                 FROM accesslist
                 WHERE employeeID = '#client.id#' and
                       a.employee_rc like concat(employeeID, '%') 
                ) ;
```

I don't see how your original query worked.  The subquery is returning two columns and that normally isn't allowed in SQL for an `in`.

Comment: This worked. I did not submit my full query because I did not want to have to change all the names..etc. Thanks this is working great.

Answer (score 0):

Move the subquery to a JOIN:

```
SELECT TOP 2500 *
    FROM table a
        LEFT JOIN table b ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
        LEFT JOIN accesslist al ON al.access LIKE concat('%', a.employee_id)
    WHERE al.employeeID = '#client.id#'
```

Like Gordon, I don't quite see how your query worked, so I'm not quite sure if it should be `access` or `employeeID` which is matched.

Answer (score 0):

This construct will enable you to do what you said you want to do, have an integer value depend on somethign from a subquery.  It's the general idea only, the details are up to you.

```
select field1, field2
, case when subqueryField1 = 'fred' then 1
when subqueryField1 = 'barney' then 2
else 3 end integerValue

from table1 t1 join (
select idField subqueryField1, etc
from whereever ) t2 on t1.idFeld = t2.idField
where whatever
```

Also, a couple of things in your query are questionable.  First, a top n query without an order by clause doesn't tell the database what records to return.  Second, 2500 rows is a lot of data to return to ColdFusion.  Are you sure you need it all?  Third, selecting * instead of just the fields you need slows down performance.  If you think you need every field, think again.  Since the employee ids will always match, you don't need both of them.

Comment: Understood. I usually just select the fields I need but for questions purposes I just put Select *. Thanks for the tips I will use them going forward.